# In Space Quest 1 VGA (not EGA) can you kill Orat with the Spider Droid?

Tags: pc, space-quest-1

In Space Quest 1 VGA (not EGA) can you kill Orat with the Spider Droid, as you can in the EGA version? I know in both you can kill him with the dehydrated water bottle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.  If I recall, you have to lure the spider drone into the Orat's den, and then hide behind the rocks at the left/bottom of the screen.

Here's a video, queued up to the point where he lures the spider drone into the den:

Comment: awesome. thank you! i wasn't hiding properly and the spider was killing me!